# Formating tooltips (help text) in BIRT 2.5?

Tags: formatting, tooltip, birt

Is it possible to format the built in tooltips (Help text propperty) of BIRT 2.5 ?
Ex: make some words bold , even insert some html content.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIRT generates tooltips in HTML outpot reports via **title** attribute  from HTML, and neither mozila or IE supports formatting in title att.